# Mongoose `let` not supported

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**Background:**
I am building a MERN Stack Travel Application and i was working to create a query to get one room object from each type of room ,from `Room` collection. i successfully managed to to do it which you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vRdPiB1VXzD) .

**Issue:**
The issue i am facing is that i was working on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/) and when i try to integrate the query i getting an error from mongoose saying `let not supported`. i can't seem to understand what i did wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Stack Trace:**

[image]

**Integration with NodeJS:**

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");
const Hotel = require("../models/HotelManagment/Hotel");

router.post("/uniquerooms", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let id = ObjectId(req.user.id);
    const uniquerooms = await Hotel.aggregate(
      [
        {
          $match: {
            hotelRep: id,
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "hotelReps",
            as: "HotelRep",
            let: {
              hotelRep: "$hotelRep",
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $eq: ["$_id", "$$hotelRep"],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "rooms",
            as: "Room",
            let: {
              id: "$_id",
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $facet: {
                  Economy: [
                    {
                      $match: {
                        $expr: {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              $eq: ["$type", "Economy"],
                            },
                            {
                              $eq: ["$hotelId", "$$id"],
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      $limit: 1,
                    },
                  ],
                  Delexue: [
                    {
                      $match: {
                        $expr: {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              $eq: ["$type", "Delexue"],
                            },
                            {
                              $eq: ["$hotelId", "$$id"],
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      $limit: 1,
                    },
                  ],
                  Luxury: [
                    {
                      $match: {
                        $expr: {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              $eq: ["$type", "Luxury"],
                            },
                            {
                              $eq: ["$hotelId", "$$id"],
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      $limit: 1,
                    },
                  ],
                },
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  activity: {
                    $setUnion: ["$Economy", "$Luxury", "$Delexue"],
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                $unwind: "$activity",
              },
              {
                $replaceRoot: {
                  newRoot: "$activity",
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$Room",
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$Room",
          },
        },
      ],
      (err, response) => {
        if (err) res.status(400).json({ err });
        console.log(uniquerooms);
        res.json(uniquerooms);
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
```

Comment: When you're trying to lookup `rooms` your code contains `var` instead of `let`: `var: {
              id: "$_id",
            }` . Can you try to change that to let ?

Comment: sorry about that, i was experimenting when the issue occured,(probably not the wisest move), but i  changed it to let and checked it stil shows  the same issue

Comment: Could you check what's your MongoDB version?

Comment: it is version 3.6

Comment: `let` was introduced in `3.6`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries

Comment: So it is probably a version issue rather than anything else,  thanks for the direction @mickl I'll see if i can resolve it somehow

Comment: "let is printed" is printed before it enters the route, it's unlikely that it's because of the aggregation. What is your node.js version? Also the HEADERS_SENT error is because you called multiple `res.json()`, try console.error(err) for the first `err` and `return res.status(400).json({ err })` instead

Comment: the node version is v12.18.0 and the `let not supported` is message from `console.log(error.message)`

Comment: i was initially using Azure Cosmos DB with version 3.6 but i tried running it locally , so there is no error now locally  i have version v4.2.7 but now the variable `$$hotelRep` does not work

Comment: i'll  ask a different question for that , thank you for your help guys. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi @AbdullahAbid same issue over here working with CosmosDB MongoAPI, how did you got around the issue?